# Start\stop scheduled task in windows server from asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to start\stop already set windows scheduled task from ASP.NET code? I have few tasks scheduled in windows server 2008 r2. They run as per their scheduled time. But I need to run few tasks manually from ASP.NET web page whenever user wants. So in addition to the tasks running at their scheduled time, I want to give user the facility to start\stop at any time from ASP.NET web application.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible -> "Task Scheduler Interfaces":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Your backend process (IIS) will need sufficient rights. Start here: [Task Scheduler 2.0 Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't want to generate custom scheduler. I want to start start the processes which are on windows server 2009 r2

Comment: Corrected my link, though it is the same direction as Kr15's answer.